# How can I do something on input checkout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).on('checkout', 'input', function(){
  alert('input is not focused anymore');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

But that alert won't be shown when I checkout of that input. I mean nothing happens when I click everywhere except focus on the input. Sorry I don't know English as well and I cannot explain what exactly I want. I want to apply something like stackoverflow's search box.

As you can see it in the top of current page, when you click on the search input *(which is into stackoverflow's header)*, the `width` of the input will be increased *(and some other css properties will be set)*, and when you click on somewhere else *(`checkout` event )*, the `width` will be toggled. I want to do something like this anyway.

Why `checkout` event has no reaction in my code?

Comment: I dont know .If `checkout` event is realy there in js

Comment: @prasad well as far as I remember, I've used it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like `checkout` event, its `blur` i.e. focus lost for an input element. It is triggers when the input lost focus.

```js
$('input:text').bind('focus blur', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
});
```

```css
input{
    background:#FFFFEE;
}
.red{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input class="calc_input" type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" />
    <input class="calc_input" type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" />
    <input class="calc_input" size="8" type="text" name="leap_year" id="leap_year" />
</form>
```

Check the above example, in this the color of input is changed on focus and re-changed on blur. In the same way you can increase the width of input and vice versa.